# CSS attribute selector priority

Tags: css, css-selectors

Anybody knows how I can achieve that the second selector (.resource-list li a[data-type="XXX"]) has a higher priority than the first (.resource-list[data-type="XXX"] li a)? Without rearranging the CSS?

```
.resource-list[data-type="jpg"] li a,
.resource-list li a[data-type="jpg"] /* This should have the highest priority */ {
    background-image: url(jpg.png);
}

.resource-list[data-type="pdf"] li a,
.resource-list li a[data-type="pdf"] /* This should have the highest priority */ {
    background-image: url(pdf.png);
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bG2j/

Comment: all you need to do is to change the order of the 2 blocks

Comment: @w3jimmy I quote from the question: _Without rearranging the CSS?_

Comment: @w3jimmy then you would still have the same issue when the situation (html structure) is reversed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bwoebi's solution is good enough, if you don't care about IE8 (which does not support `:not()`)

An alternative is to decrease the specificity of the first part of the selectors.

```
.resource-list[data-type="jpg"] a, /* less specific after omitting the "li" */
.resource-list li a[data-type="jpg"] {
    color: black;
}

.resource-list[data-type="pdf"] a,
.resource-list li a[data-type="pdf"] {
    color: red;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8bG2j/4/

Comment: This was the key! I've tried this sooner, but it did not workend - maybe I misstyped something. Anyways - now it's working. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/8bG2j/2/

This should do it. Simply use a pseudoclass which is always true like `a:not(s)`.

It will raise your priority by the priority of the selector inside the :not statement.

Alternatively, *as stated in the comments*, you can prefix it with an `ul` when you don't want to break with older browsers (like IE 8). You can do this if `.ressource-list` will be always a class of an `<ul>` tag.

Comment: @Andy yes, but the it'll bound to the ul. I didn't want to change the possibly targeted elements.

Comment: :not() on its own does not have any specificity. the added specificity comes from the selector inside ("s" in this case)

Comment: @xec thanks, just reread the w3 specification; they used there an example with `#id:not(FOO)` and I thought FOO + pseudoclass would give 101; and not because of the #id...

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply bound a `<ul>` type selector in front of the class name, `.resource-list` for two latter selectors - as `:not()` isnt [supported](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3) below IE9: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8bG2j/5/)

```
.resource-list[data-type="jpg"] li a,
ul.resource-list li a[data-type="jpg"]  {
    background-image: url(jpg.png);
}

.resource-list[data-type="pdf"] li a,
ul.resource-list li a[data-type="pdf"]  { 
    background-image: url(pdf.png);
}
```